# Finding a parity check matrix for a generator in non-standard form

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

Suppose that a certain linear code in $\mathbb{F}_3$ has the generator matrix

$G=\left[\begin{array}{lllllll}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1\end{array}\right]$

Is there a way to quickly find a parity check matrix $H$ for $G$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?